# HTTP Only JSessionID not sent back in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, http, session-cookies

I am facing a weird issue.

I have started my tomcat server. I am using angular js as the frontend UI.
When I login, I can see a jsessionId in the response header as HTTP Only.

Now when I send any request back to the server request back to the server in chrome, I cannot see this cookie being sent back and hence I am not able to hold the session.

When I test it on IE 11, it can see the cookie being sent back on every request and my session is working perfectly

Comment: What is the cookie's `Domain` attribute value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was accessing the application at http://localhost:8080/

Now when I start accessing the application at http://127.0.0.1:8080/ it works fine.

Chrome is able to send the cookies back.

This looks like a bad thing in chrome